# Error 800A01CE, add printer by vbs throught ip

Tags: vbscript, ip, wsh

When I tried a small code to add printer on window 10 enterprise 64bits. I meet error 800A01CE. Please help me to resolve this problem. This is my source

```
Option Explicit
Dim strPrinterUNC, objNetwork 

strPrinterUNC = "\\10.95.200.11\HP LaserJet 400" 

Set objNetwork = createObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strPrinterUNC
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter strPrinterUNC 

Set objNetwork = Nothing
MsgBox ("Add printer successfully")
```

My error as image.

I tried change strPrinterUNC manytime, but I still got the error above. Please suggest me the way to custom my code.
[image]Thank you,

Comment: Did you [ask the bingleduck about that error](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+error+0x800A01CE)? It seems to indicate that it can't connect to the computer at 10.95.200.11. Check your network connection.

Comment: Think the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I setup manual successful. I don't think the error from network (I tried ping to ip, it's very fast)

Comment: Are you running the script with elevated permissions?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run this script with admin permissions but still got the same error.